# What's the purpose of such code?

Tags: perl

```
253:        my $sel = select(FOUT);
254:        $| = 1;                             # for DB::OUT
255:        select($sel);
```

Looks really weird to me,spotted in `Term::ReadLine` module.

Comment: See: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/select.html and OUTPUT_AUTOFLUSH in http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html

Answer (score 8):

> Writing to STDOUT (or any other output filehandle) is buffered by
>   default. To ask Perl to flush immediately after each write or print
>   command, set the special variable $| to 1.

http://www.perlhowto.com/disable_output_buffering

**edit:** for further explanation:

```
my $sel = select(FOUT);
```

`FOUT` is a file handle, using `select` makes it the `default file handle` so that any operation using the `default file handle` will now use `FOUT`.  For example `print "moo"` will be the equivalent to `print FOUT "moo"`.

The return value of `select` is the previous `default file handle`, i.e. standard output.

```
$| = 1;
```

This command disables output buffering on the `default file handle`, as the handle is `FOUT` is disables output buffering for `FOUT`.

```
select($sel);
```

Now we bring back the previous `default file handle`, i.e. standard output, so `print` commands, etc, work as expected.

**edit #2:** further explanation of file handles:

Imagine you have a series of file handles, `STDOUT`, `FILE_ONE`, `FILE_TWO`, `SOCKET_ONE`, and `SOCKET_TWO`.  You want to set `FILE_ONE` and `SOCKET_TWO` to have no output buffering.

```
# On startup Perl effectively does the following:
# select(STDOUT);
my $sel = select(FILE_ONE);
# $sel is now STDOUT
$| = 1;
select(SOCKET_TWO);
$| = 1;
# bring back STDOUT
select($sel);
```

Now lets discover what happens with that magical `default file handle`.

```
print "HELLO\n";
# equivalent to: print STDOUT "HELLO\n";
my $sel = select(FILE_ONE);
# sets `default file handle` to FILE_ONE
print "HELLO\n";
# equivalent to: print FILE_ONE "HELLO\n";
$| = 1;
# disables output buffering on handle FILE_ONE
select(SOCKET_TWO)
# sets `default file handle` to SOCKET_TWO
print "HELLO\n";
# equivalent to: print SOCKET_TWO "HELLO\n";
$| = 1;
# disables output buffering on handle SOCKET+TWO
select($sel);
# sets `default file handle` to STDOUT
```

Alternatively lets invent some a new variable:

```
$FH
# let this be the `default file handle`
```

Lets invent a new function:

```
sub disable_output_buffer ($file_handle) {
# magic occurs here
}
```

Now lets rewrite the previous code using this new file handle and function.

```
# print "HELLO\n";
my $FH = STDOUT;
print $FH "HELLO\n"           # print STDOUT "HELLO\n"

# my $sel = select(FILE_ONE);
my $sel = $FH;
$FH = FILE_ONE;

# print "HELLO\n";
print $FH "HELLO\n";          # print FILE_ONE "HELLO\n"

# $| = 1
disable_output_buffer ($FH);  # disable_output_buffer (FILE_ONE)

# select(SOCKET_TWO);
$FH = SOCKET_TWO;

# print "HELLO\n";
print $FH "HELLO\n";          # print SOCKET_TWO "HELLO\n"

# $| = 1
disable_output_buffer ($FH);  # disable_output_buffer (SOCKET_TWO)

# select($sel);
$FH = $sel;
```

Comment: So it only affects `FOUT`,not `$sel`?

Comment: How does it work? say, `$|` only affect the current file handle?

Comment: I mean **how**,as you see ,it's not binded to any specific namespace related with `FOUT`.

Comment: I mean,after the `default file handle` is changed back to `$sel`,how does perl know `$|` should affect on `FOUT`?

Comment: But you said `$|`'s effect is sticky to `FOUT` in the above code,even when it's no longer the `default file handle` any more.

Comment: Which do you mean by `STDOUT` here? There's only `FOUT` and `$sel` in the  context...

Comment: If that's the case,why not `$| = 1;` directly,the other two statements seem useless in that case?

Comment: You don't need to invent a function, since it already exists: `use IO::Handle; $fh->autoflush();`

Comment: @new_perl, `STDOUT` is the handle that's normally selected.

Comment: @ikegami I was trying to simplify the explanation, clearly failing :(

Comment: @new_perl, changing `$|` immediately affects the handle that's currently being returned by `select`. Don't think of `$|` as a variable, but a reflection of a property of the currently selected handle.

Comment: ＠ikegami,is there a way to see how perl interpreter handles `$|=..` statement at all?

Answer (score 0):

it's an old form of

```
use IO::Handle;
FOUT->autoflush(1);
```